# How do I Understand the difference between FOR EACH and FOR FIRST?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am new to progress and I would like to know what's the difference between FOR EACH and FOR FIRST. I tried to know but don't get understandable and acceptable reason. I have written a small query and got same result.Let me share

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt_data
    FIELD womf AS CHARACTER
    FIELD pomf AS CHARACTER.

CREATE tt_data.
ASSIGN
    tt_data.womf = "BlockCar"
    tt_data.pomf = "Whitecar".


FOR EACH tt_data.
    DISPLAY tt_data.womf.
END.

FOR FIRST tt_data.
    DISPLAY tt_data.womf.
END.
```

if my query is wrong then please give me an example to understand the difference please. I need to use FOR FIRST.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to use FOR FIRST?

Comment: Because as I new to progress I need to go through all programs to understand that how the logic is going. In our company employees written most of the codes with FOR FIRST. That's the reason I would like to know what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference when there's just a single record.

When there are multiple records, FOR EACH processes every record, one after the other.

FOR FIRST would still only process a single record.

Comment: Mike is correct as always, but I believe there's a crucial difference that deserves to be mentioned: for first leaves the record in scope after its end, while for each does not. To illustrate, this code will show you an error: FOR EACH tt_data: end. Display tt_data.  And this code works: FOR FIRST tt_data: end. Display tt_data.

Comment: I'm probably nit picking but FOR EACH will also leave the record in scope if you LEAVE the block.  If the block is allowed to complete normally the query runs off the end and there is no current record to be in scope.

Comment: Correct, Tom, and very well put.

Answer (score 3):

As Mike says, when there is just one record (like in your sample code) there is no difference.

When there are multiple records FOR EACH processes the whole set as defined by the WHERE clause (if it is present) and sorted by the BY clause (if it is present).

FOR FIRST can also have a WHERE and a BY.  However -- FOR FIRST only ever works with ONE record.  This can be extremely confusing if you specify sorting that differs from the index that the WHERE clause results in (or the lack thereof defaults to).  The FIRST (and only) record returned by the query will be "sorted".  In other words the BY has no impact on selection.

The following sports2000 example makes this clear:

```
for each customer no-lock where custNum > 10 by name:
  display custNum name.
end.
pause.

for first customer no-lock where custNum > 10 by name:
  display custNum name.
end.
```

Using FOR FIRST is almost always a mistake and a bug waiting to happen.  Doubly so if a BY clause is specified.